# Deck of $132$ different cards, $200$ draws with replacement

Tags: probability

So we have a deck of $132$ (unique) cards, and we draw $100$ cards (with replacement). What is the $\%$ of unique cards that we can expect in the $100$ cards drawn?

I started that question with the number of possibilities of pulling a $100$ unique cards successively from a deck of $132$ divided by the total number of ways of pulling $100$ cards from a deck of $132$, so:
$$\frac{(132!/32!)}{(132^{100})}$$

But that's not really what I am after. Somehow I cannot get my head around this problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What value are you looking for?  The number of unique cards with the highest probability?

Comment: I would maybe do this calculation with fewer cars first, say you have five cards and you draw two or three of them. Then it should be easier to see how it translates to larger decks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are looking for expected number of **unique cards (singleton)** among the 100 cards drawn.

Number your 132 cards, denote the random variable $I_1,I_2,...,I_{132} $ as 
$${I_k} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1\space\space\space\space\space{\text{if the }}k{\text{th card has been drawn exactly once}}}\\
{0\space\space\space\space{\text{ else}}}
\end{array}} \right.$$

Then $$E[I_k]=P\left\{ {{I_k} = 1} \right\}=\frac{{100}}{{132}}{\left( {\frac{{131}}{{132}}} \right)^{99}}$$

Hence the expected number of unique cards drawn is
$$E[I_1+I_2+...+I_{132}]=E[I_1]+E[I_2]+...+E[I_{132}]=100{\left( {\frac{{131}}{{132}}} \right)^{99}}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure (yet) but this might be what you are after.

Number the cards ($i=1,\dots,132$) and let $X_i$ be a random variable that takes value $1$ if card $i$ is drawn exactly once (is this the right interpretation of a "unique" card that is drawn?), and let it take value $0$ otherwise. The number of cards drawn exactly once is $X:=X_1+\cdots+X_{132}$. 
Its expectation is $$\mathbb EX_1+\cdot+\mathbb EX_{132}=132\mathbb EX_1=132\mathbb P(X_1=1)$$

Then:$$100\times\frac{\mathbb EX}{132}=100\times\mathbb P(X_1=1)$$ is the expected percentage of cards that are drawn exactly once. This as percentage of the total number of cards.

$$100\times\frac{\mathbb EX}{100}=132\times\mathbb P(X_1=1)$$ is the expected percentage of cards that are drawn exactly once. This as percentage of the total number of cards that have been drawn.

So it remains to find $\mathbb P(X_1=1)$. Can you do that?

Comment: The OP might also be after the number of distinct cards that have been drawn, as opposed to the number of cards that have been drawn exactly once. It's difficult to tell. However, this answer seems to work equally good in either case; you would just need to revise the definition of $X_i$ slightly.